# Softlayer Api Authentication with Terraform

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-schematics

I exported the SL_USERNAME and SL_API_KEY variables. I did not link my softlayer account to bluemix.

**Command:**

```
terraform import ibmcloud_infra_vlan.999 999
```

**Error:**

```
import ibmcloud_infra_vlan.999 result: 999: ibmcloud_infra_vlan.999: Error communicating with the API: SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Access Denied.  (HTTP 401)
```

Does this mean user doesn't have permission for API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So username seems to be the API Username. Not the one you see in the users page.

And VLAN ID is in the URL. https://control.softlayer.com/network/vlans/vlanid

The same goes for all the other resource ID's.

And you have to modify allowed IP's for the user you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Terraform but this post may help you [How do I create a SoftLayer Vlan using Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509756/how-do-i-create-a-softlayer-vlan-using-terraform).

To know if you are able to made a request using your username and api key you can perform a single REST call using a client or any web browser.

Following is an example you can use to verify API access. It should returns information about your SL account.

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject

Method: GET
```

Replace **[userName]** and **[apiKey]** with your own data. If response says **"Access Denied"**. I recommend you verify if userName and apiKey are correct using the Control portal (Profile).

Take account that API user should be able to perform same actions he is able to do in Control portal page. For example, if user isn't able to see vlans then he will not be able to do it through API.

Comment: Hey Albert! Thank you for the comment. I do see account info on that page. I was previously using the primary user which doesn't seem to have a username. I get a new error now `import ibmcloud_infra_vlan.999 result: 999: import ibmcloud_infra_vlan.999 (id: 999): Terraform detected a resource with this ID doesn't exist. Please verify the ID is correct.` I don't see anything as VLAN ID in the portal. All I see is VLAN number. Also the link you pasted above exports SL_USERNAME as API Username, which doesn't seem to work for me.